# QTableView row remove

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qpushbutton, row-removal

I created a table view like this:

[image]

I have a create button to create new rows and as you can see I defined a button for each row to delete that row by this code:

```
int i = 0;
QPushButton *viewButton;
QStandardItemModel *model;
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(QString("")));
    viewButton = new QPushButton();
    viewButton->setText("Delete " + QString::number(i));
    ui->tableView->setIndexWidget(model->index(i , 7), viewButton);
    connect(viewButton , SIGNAL(clicked()) , this , SLOT(button_clicked()));
    i++;
}
```

and I created a slot for each button clicked for remove a row:

```
void MainWindow::button_clicked()
{
//   by this line I can get the sender of signal
    QPushButton *pb = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(QObject::sender());
}
```

as you can see I know witch button sends signal and now I need to delete that row.
here is my question:
how can I get the row of sender button in table view to remove that row?
I searched everywhere and I didn’t realise how to get the row and column of an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On workaround is to use `QObject::setObjectName` and set some names to the buttons you add :

```
viewButton.setObjectName(QString("%1").arg(i));
```

And in `button_clicked` slot you can retrieve the row number using the object name :

```
void MainWindow::button_clicked()
{
//   by this line I can get the sender of signal
    QPushButton *pb = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(QObject::sender());

    int row = pb->objectName().toInt();
}
```

Note that you should update object names after a row is removed.

Another way is to use the `QSignalMapper` class which collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal. So you can have one like:

```
QSignalMapper * mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
QObject::connect(mapper,SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this,SLOT(button_clicked(int)));
```

When adding your buttons in each row of table view, you can connect the `clicked()` signal of the button to the `map()` slot of `QSignalMapper` and add a mapping using `setMapping` so that when `clicked()` is signaled from a button, the signal `mapped(int)` is emitted:

```
viewButton = new QPushButton();
viewButton->setText("Delete " + QString::number(i));
ui->tableView->setIndexWidget(model->index(i , 7), viewButton);

QObject::connect(viewButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),mapper,SLOT(map()));
mapper->setMapping(but, i);
```

This way whenever you click a button in a row, the `mapped(int)` signal of the mapper is emitted containing the row number and consequently `button_clicked` is called with a parameter containing the row number.

Also here you should update the mappings in `button_clicked` slot since the row is removed when you click an item.

Comment: thank for your answer dear nejat. but I have some issues with your answer. after using remove function rows will sort again. and row indexes will change. but in your code button's indexes are kind of static. am I right?

Comment: sorry but still I think object name doesn't show the row after some remove. if there is a way that I can resort buttons after each delete that would be great! but if I missed something in your answer please tell me.

Comment: @ATN You should update object names or mapping after each remove. I can't think of anything else.